# python epsilon wrong calculation

Tags: python

epsilon is set to 0.1 but it gives me results until 1.2. I dont know what causes that. Can anyone help?

```
def evaluate_poly(poly, x):
    total = 0.0
    for i in range(len(poly)):
        total += poly[i] * (x ** i)

    return total

def compute_deriv(poly):
    deriv = []
    if len(poly) < 2:
        return  [0.0]
    else:
        for i in range(1, len(poly)):
            deriv.append(float(poly[i] * i))
        return deriv

def compute_root(poly, x_0, epsilon):
    num = 0
    root = x_0
    while abs(evaluate_poly(poly, root)) >= epsilon:
        root = root - evaluate_poly(poly, root) / evaluate_poly(compute_deriv(poly), root)
        num += 1
    return [root, num]

print(compute_root((1.0,-2.0,1.0), 14, 0.1))
```

Comment: Please first specify your problem: what is epsilon, what do you want to calculate,...

Comment: "epsilon is set to 1.1" -- your code seems to use 0.1. "but it gives me results until 1.2." -- what does that even mean? You would need to supply more details if you want to convince anyone that what you are seeing is anything more than floating point round-off error.

Comment: @SergeBallesta I understand that (although it looks more like Newton's method) but their code used epsilon = 0.1 whereas in the question they said that they had set epsilon to 1.1.

Comment: sorry it should have been 0.1, and it is actually newtons method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to solve numerically x<sup>2</sup> - 2 * x + 1 = 0. We know that the equation has a double root at x=1. But at that point (x=1), the derivative (2 * x - 2) is 0. That mean that the error in y will always be one magnitude order below the error in x, so the result of x = 1.2, y ~ 0.04 < 0.1 is not at all a surprise.

The difference x<sub>n</sub> - x<sub>n-1</sub> would be a much better guess of the error in x:

```
def compute_root1(poly, x_0, epsilon):
    num = 0
    root = x_0
    while True:
        root1 = root - evaluate_poly(poly, root) / evaluate_poly(compute_deriv(poly), root)
        if abs(root1 - root) < epsilon: break
        num += 1
        root = root1
    return [root1, num+1]
```

It gives:

```
>>> print(compute_root1((1.0,-2.0,1.0), 14, 0.1))
[1.05078125, 8]
```

Answer (score 2):

epsilon represents y error (evaluate poly if you will), but your result of 1.2... is x value, where y is 0. in this case your y is 0.0412 and is lower than 0.1 so code is ok.

change your return in compute_root to:

```
return [root, num, abs(evaluate_poly(poly, root))]
```